# Trying to show that $(c_0, \| \cdot \|_s)$ is strictly convex, where $\| x \|_s = \underset{i = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \frac{1}{2^i} | x_i |$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to show that $ (c_0, \| \cdot \|_s) $ is a strictly convex space, where 
$$ \| x \|_s = \underset{i = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \frac{1}{2^i} | x_i |,$$
$ x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_i, ...) \in c_0 $.

Let $x, y \in c_0, \| x \|_s = \| y \|_s = 1, x \neq y $. Let $\lambda \in (0 , 1)$.

$$ \| \lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y \|_s = \| (\lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda) y_i)_i \|_s $$
 $$ = \underset{i = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \frac{1}{2^i} | \lambda x_i + (1 - \lambda) y_i | $$
 $$\leq \underset{i = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \frac{1}{2^i} ( \lambda | x_i | + (1 - \lambda) | y_i | ) $$
$$ = \lambda \underset{i = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \frac{1}{2^i} | x_i | + (1 - \lambda) \underset{i = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \frac{1}{2^i} | y_i | $$
$$ = \lambda \| x \|_s + (1 - \lambda) \| y \|_s = \lambda + 1 - \lambda = 1. $$
So,

$$ \| \lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y \|_s \leq 1. $$
How can I show that 
$$ \| \lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y \|_s \neq 1 $$?

Than you!

Comment: If $x_i$ and $y_i$ are positive for all $i$, then isn't there equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=(2,0,0\cdots)$ and $y=(0,4,0,0,\cdots)$. Both are in $c_0$, and we have

$$\| \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \|_s = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\lambda x_i + (1-\lambda)y_i|}{2^i}$$

$$= \frac{2\lambda}{2} + \frac{4(1-\lambda)}{4} =1$$

Hence your space is not strictly convex

Comment: Yes, thank you. I must change the norm.